# Why the the record can not be saved when there is attr_accessor in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

When I add

```
  attr_accessor :minor_edit, :title, :body, :slug, :domain_id
```

in my Post model, when I save the model by

```
  post = Post.new(:title => "123", body => "456")
  post.save
```

The database said the title column is null

Comment: can you paste the error and validations applied to Post model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `attr_accessor :title` you override ActiveRecords setter method. You want to use `attr_accessible` instead to stop mass assignment.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html